# Javascript function in asp:Multiview + asp.Wizard

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've an asp.net page
 which contains asp:MultiView 
which contains  asp:View and an asp:Wizard ID="wizardIscrizione 
which contains 20 textboxes.(ID= txtNome1, txtCognome1, txtNome2, txtCognome2 and so on ).
 Half of textboxes are in wizard Step1 and the other half on Wizard Step2.
My javascript function is set to on onchange textbox event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function CalcolaJs() {
           var contaIscritti = 0;

           for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
               var conta = (i).toString();

               var nome = document.getElementById('wizardIscrizione_' + 'txtNome' + conta).value;
               var cognome = document.getElementById('wizardIscrizione_' + 'txtCognome' + conta).value;

               if (((nome != "") && (nome !== null) && (nome !== undefined)) &&
                 ((cognome != "") && (cognome !== null) && (cognome !== undefined)))

                   contaIscritti = contaIscritti + 1;
               else contaIscritti = contaIscritti;

               document.getElementById('hidNumPartecipanti').value = contaIscritti;
               document.getElementById('lblNumPartecipanti').innerHTML = contaIscritti;}
           }        
       } 
</script>
```

Javascript function works fine for textboxes in wizard Step 1 but doesn't in Step 2. I really don't know why!
EDIT:
asp.net source:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
  <asp:View ID="VistaIscrizione" runat="server">
    <asp:Wizard ID="wizardIscrizione" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" CancelButtonStyle-CssClass="button" FinishCompleteButtonStyle-CssClass="button" FinishPreviousButtonStyle-CssClass="button" NavigationButtonStyle-CssClass="button" FinishCompleteButtonText="Conferma" StartNextButtonText="Avanti &gt;&gt;" StepNextButtonText="Avanti &gt;&gt;" StepPreviousButtonText="&lt;&lt; Indietro" OnFinishButtonClick="wizardIscrizione_FinishButtonClick" DisplaySideBar="False" Width="100%" OnActiveStepChanged="wizardIscrizione_ActiveStepChanged">
        <WizardSteps>
          <asp:WizardStep ID="StepPartecipanti1" runat="server" Title="Step 1 di 3 - Inserisci il nominativo dei partecipanti">
              <fieldset class="gradientCoolBlack">
                  <legend></legend>
                  <p class="titoloStep">Nominativo dei Partecipanti</p>
                  <p><asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" CssClass="label">?&nbsp;Nome e Cognome:</asp:Label></p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 1. " />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r001" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome1" />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r002" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCognome1" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome1" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"/>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome1" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"/>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 2. " />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r18" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome2" />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r19" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCognome2" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome2" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome2" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15" />
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 3. " />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r16" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome3" />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r17" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCognome3" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome3" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome3" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label181" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 4. " />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r22" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome4" />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r23" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCognome4" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome4" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15" ></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome4" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 5. " />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r20" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome5" />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r21" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCognome5" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome5" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome5" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <span style="color: White">Altri Partecipanti</span>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAltri" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkAltri_CheckedChanged" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCounter" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                      </p>
                  <p>
                      &nbsp;</p>
              </fieldset>

          </asp:WizardStep>
          <asp:WizardStep ID="StepPartecipanti2" runat="server" Title="Step 1 di 3 - Inserisci il nominativo dei partecipanti">
              <fieldset class="gradientCoolBlack">
                  <legend></legend>
                  <p style="text-align: right; font-size: 18px; font-family: Candara; color: #17ef1f">
                      Nominativo dei Partecipanti</p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" CssClass="label">?&nbsp;Nome e Cognome:</asp:Label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 6. " />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r24" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNome6"/>
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r25" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCognome6"/>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome6" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome6" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label121" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 7. " />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome7" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome7" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 8. " />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome8" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome8" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text=" 9. " />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome9" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome9" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="20px" Text="10. " />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome10" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCognome10" runat="server" CssClass="input" Width="250px" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      &nbsp;</p>
              </fieldset>
          </asp:WizardStep>
</asp:MultiView>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  AddOnChangeAttribute(Page);//Add .Attributes.Add("onchange","CalcolaIscrittiJs()") to txtNome(i) and txtCognome(i);

  numeroPartecipanti = Convert.ToInt16(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Page.Request.Form["hidNumPartecipanti"]));

  hidNumPartecipanti.Value = numeroPartecipanti.ToString();//valore pagina 2
  lblNumPartecipanti.Text = hidNumPartecipanti.Value;
}
```

Comment: can you post the aspx view control source?nothing fishy here in code but why are you using this code "else contaIscritti = contaIscritti;"

Comment: Add done, thanks. You're right: else block is not necessary

Comment: you check your's input id on the html source.if input id's prefix not error but  not fine input ,so it is javascript issues.you need firefox firebug.

Comment: can you point out the id of textbox which is causing problem or not working

Comment: lets try first thing set property of textbox clientidmode=static and then onchange of textbox run javascript function like this functextchange(this);let me know if it didnt work

Comment: @skhuramas Only textboxes with ID from txtNome1 to txtNome5 and from txtCognome1 to txtCognome5 work. Add ClientIDMode="Static" but nothing change

Comment: please set all textbox ClientModeID="Static" it will make the id same as in browser when you see in firebug and then onchange of textbox run javascript function like this functextchange(this);let me know if it didnt work

Comment: second opinion use alert to show what is in variable i thing your variable is null 
use alert( document.getElementById('wizardIscrizione_' + 'txtCognome' + conta).value;);and then tell me whats going on

Comment: alert added: alert messagebox is ok for textbox 1-5. in second page alert is not firing!!!! It seems that my javascript function doesn't fire at all in second page.